# Attach user_id and meeting_id into pivot table

Tags: angular, laravel

I have a users table, a meetings table, and a pivot table (meeting_users).

I created a users CRUD controller and a meetings CRUD controller.

When a user registers, they are added to the user table with status 1 (means organizer) and attendee 1 (means attend the event). When he is logged, he can create a meeting.

This meeting has a title, a place and a day. The organizer can publish this meeting with URL.  Attendees can see these fields, and there is a form with name and radio button (yes or no) to indicate attendance. Users can send their name and whether or not they want to attend the meeting.

When a user submits this form, they should be added to the users table, with status 2 (means invited) and attendee 0 or 1 (depends on whether or not they attend the event).

So far I've been able to do it, but:

**This record should also be added to the pivot table, this table controls the relationship between attendees and meetings, to know which attendee is attending which meeting. This relationship is used to list the guests signed up for each meeting.**

I don't know how to create the method to do this...

I'm using Laravel and Angular.

This is my UserController in Laravel:

```
        public function registerUser(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'attendee' => $request->attendee
        ]);

        $user->meetings()->attach('meeting_id');

        return response()->json([
            "missatge" => 'Usuari registrat correctament',
            $user
        ], 200);
    }
```

But this method doesn't work.

This is my angular component:

```
export class ShareComponent implements OnInit {
  meeting: MeetingDTO;
  user: UserDTO;
  name: FormControl;
  attendee: FormControl;
  attendeeForm: FormGroup;

  meetingId!: string | null;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private meetService: MeetingService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.user = new UserDTO('', '', '', 2, false);

    this.name = new FormControl(this.user.name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(55),
    ]);

    this.attendee = new FormControl(this.user.attendee, Validators.required);

    this.attendeeForm = this.fb.group({
      name: this.name,
      attendee: this.attendee,
      status: 2,
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.meetingId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.meetService.getMeetingById(this.meetingId).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.meeting = data;
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err.error);
      },
    });
  }

  registerAttendee() {
    const register = this.attendeeForm.value;
    this.userService.registerUser(register).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('');
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err.error);
      },
    });
  }
```

My models are:

meetings.php:

```
    public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

users.php:

```
public function meetings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Meeting::class);
}
```

And this is userService

```
  registerUser(user: UserDTO): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/register-users', user);
```

}

**I need a guest to be able to register as a guest, and for that, needs the meeting ID (to the URL), and create a new user_id, and the two id's are added to the pivot table.**

Comment: "But this method doesn't work.", show the error message from your laravel.log. try to explain exactly what you need done

Comment: You should also send what is the `meeting id`  when the user submit the form so that you can insert it in the `attach()` method

Answer (score 0):

The following solution might solve your problem.

This is the new method in the MeetingController:

```
public function registerAttendee(Request $request, Meeting $meeting)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            'status' => $request->status,
            'attendee' => $request->attendee
        ]);

        $meeting_id = $meeting->id;
        $user_id = $user->id;

        $user->meetings()->attach([$user_id => ['meeting_id' => $meeting_id]]);

        return response()->json([
            "missatge" => 'Usuari registrat correctament',
            $user
        ], 200);
    }
```

This is the new route

```
Route::post('meetings/{meeting}', [MeetingController::class, 'registerAttendee']);
```

This is the service on MeetingService

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.urlApi = 'http://localhost:8000/api/meetings/';
  }

  registerUser(user: UserDTO, meetingId: string | null): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.urlApi + meetingId, user);
  }
```

And this is the Angular-component:

```
export class ShareComponent implements OnInit {
  meeting: MeetingDTO;
  user: UserDTO;
  name: FormControl;
  attendee: FormControl;
  attendeeForm: FormGroup;

  meetingId!: string | null;

  constructor(
    private meetService: MeetingService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.user = new UserDTO('', '', '', 1, true);

    this.name = new FormControl(this.user.name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(55),
    ]);

    this.attendee = new FormControl(this.user.attendee, Validators.required);

    this.attendeeForm = this.fb.group({
      name: this.name,
      status: 1,
      attendee: this.attendee,
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.meetingId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.meetService.getMeetingById(this.meetingId).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.meeting = data;
        console.log(this.meeting);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err.error);
      },
    });
  }

  registerAttendee() {
    const register = this.attendeeForm.value;

    this.meetService.registerUser(register, this.meetingId).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err.error);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

I don't know if my approach is best practise, but it seems to work. Now I can register a `user-guest` and send `the user_id` and `meeting_id` (by URL) to the pivot table.

I still struggle to receive the value from the radio button in `ShareComponent` (it always returns false). Unfortunately `formControl` doesn't work for this, but this is another story.

Thanks for your responses.